# 403 error in accessing localhost after wamp installation, despite having "Allow from 127.0.0.1" in apache conf

Tags: localhost, wamp, http-status-code-403, access-denied, apache-config

I've just installed Wamp and I'm getting 403 access denied error when I try to access `http://localhost`.
I've checked my apache configuration file and it has the line `Allow from 127.0.0.1` in both `<Directory />` and `<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">` sections.
So why the access to root directory is forbidden for localhost?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the OS, Apache may be binding to IPv6 address, so the `localhost` is recognizing as `::1` instead of `127.0.0.1`.
You have to add `Allow from ::1` instead of `Allow from 127.0.0.1` in apache config file.
**NOTE**: Problem can be solved also if you add `Allow from all` to root directory section in http config file, but it's not a good idea because this way your web root became accessible from any computer in the network you are.